# When is Spring Boot app ready to receive HTTP requests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have:

1. multiple `ApplicationRunners`
2. and multiple `@Scheduled` jobs that run immediately after the app starts, and periodically after that.

I want to write a message to the log when the app is ready to handle HTTP requests; so that I verify all necessary jobs have been executed before the app can accept HTTP requests.

1. Q1: How/Where to write this log message?
2. Q2: How to run code before accepting HTTP requests?

Note: my app extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`

Comment: Why the log? As soon as the `ApplicationRunner` instances have finished the application is ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered by @m-deinum, The app won't accept HTTP traffic until all `ApplicationRunner` beans have finished running.

I have verified this.
I am closing this question.

Comment: I can't verify this. My Spring Boot app accepts network traffic before the Application runners are done.

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationRunner` will make sure all of Spring Bean's lifecycle is completed and then only take HTTP traffic, but if you listening to `ApplicationReadyEvent` and building cache or anything on `ApplicationReadyEvent` then `ApplicationRunner` won't wait for `ApplicationReadyEvent`.